# It is possible to discover and manage a MediaPlayer of another application in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: uwp, media-player

I would like to control the media player of another application running on my Xbox. It is possible to discover the MediaPlayer and control it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could refer Use the system media transport controls for background audio [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls#use-the-system-media-transport-controls-for-background-audio). you could manually integrate with the SMTC to enable background audio.

```
SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView().IsPlayEnabled = true;
SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView().IsPauseEnabled = true;
```